# Angular2/4/5 - Reactive Forms, should you use AbstractControl or FormControl?

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

In different projects I have worked on I have seen the following 2 different ways to build reactive forms. Which one is the recommended way?

**Using AbstractControl**

```
  public form: FormGroup;
  public fb: FormBuilder;
  public to: AbstractControl;
  public subject: AbstractControl;
  public body: AbstractControl;

  private ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'to': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, emailValidator])],
      'subject': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'body': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    });
    this.to = this.form.controls['to'];
    this.subject = this.form.controls['subject'];
    this.body = this.form.controls['body'];
  }
```

**Using FormControl**

```
  public form: FormGroup;
  public fb: FormBuilder;
  public to: FormControl;
  public subject: FormControl;
  public body: FormControl;

  private ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'to': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, emailValidator])],
      'subject': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'body': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    });
    this.to = new FormControl['to'];
    this.subject = new FormControl['subject'];
    this.body = new FormControl['body'];
  }
```

I also found that the [docs here](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) states that AbstractControl should not be instantiated directly, so does that mean method 1 is not the recommended way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AbstractControl is the base class for most form controls.  According to the documentation, you should use the child class -- FormControl -- to instantiate form controls primarily where you get value and validator status for each ui object.

```
const body = new FormControl({value: 'n/a', disabled: true});
console.log(body.status); // disabled
console.log(body.value);  // n/a
```